How can I make my dynamic route work in NextJs?
// /home/[storeId]/layout.tsx
import prismadb from "@/lib/prismadb";
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default async function DashboardLayout({
 children,
 params,
}: {
children: React.ReactNode;
params: { storeId: string };
}) {
const { userId } = auth();

if (!userId) {
redirect("/sign-in");
}
const store = await prismadb.store.findFirst({
 where: {
   id: params.storeId,
   userId,
 },
 });

if (!store) {
 redirect("/home");
}

return (
 <>
   <div>Navbar</div>
   {children}
 </>
);
}

//  /home/[storeId]/page.tsx
import React from "react";

const Dashboard = () => {
return <div>Dashboard</div>;
};
export default Dashboard;

//  /home/layout.tsx

import prismadb from "@/lib/prismadb";
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default async function SetupLayout({
 children,
}: {
 children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
const { userId } = auth();

if (!userId) {
 redirect("/sign-in");
}

const store = await prismadb.store.findFirst({
 where: {
   userId,
 },
});

if (store) {
 redirect(`/home/${store.id}`);
}

return <>{children}</>;
}

//  /home/page.tsx

"use client";
import { useEffect } from "react";

import { useStoreModal } from "@/hooks/use-store-modal";

const Home = () => {
 const onOpen = useStoreModal((state) => state.onOpen);
 const isOpen = useStoreModal((state) => state.isOpen);

 useEffect(() => {
  if (!isOpen) {
   onOpen();
  }
 }, [isOpen, onOpen]);
 return null;
export default Home;

// /hooks/use-store-modal.tsx

import { create } from "zustand";

interface useStoreModalStore {
 isOpen: boolean;
 onOpen: () => void;
 onClose: () => void;
}

export const useStoreModal = create<useStoreModalStore>((set) => 
({
 isOpen: false,
 onOpen: () => set({ isOpen: true }),
 onClose: () => set({ isOpen: false }),
}));

enter image description here

I am new to NextJs, and I am trying to build an App with it, but I kinda face a problem when I try to create a dynamic route in the App in my "home" folder. The idea is to redirect me to a store page using the store id, but so far it is not successful. I tried to do in on the project root and it worked perfectly, but when I try to do it in my home folder, I either get a 404 message, or I get a message saying "Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information)". Since I am new to NextJs, I don't fully understand how to debug it. I would very much appreciate your help. Thanks.

what is the client side exception? have you looked in the browser console?

Yes, I have. The console was not very helpful, it gave hundreds of lines of infinite errors.

Can you provide the error you get in the console? It might actually be more useful than you think.

@JeanMako Were the errors constantly scrolling by (like the program was in an actual infinite loop) or do you mean it as hyperbole for a lot of errors. In either case nobody is going to be able to help without the error message. Even if someone actually wanted to run it (they don't) there are too many external dependencies.

@le3th4x0rbot Yes, the program was running forever. I will try to submit the error screenshot

@le3th4x0rbot, the console error has been added to the question.

@moonstar-x the console error has been added to the question.

You're creating an infinite loop with this bit right here:
 const onOpen = useStoreModal((state) => state.onOpen);
 const isOpen = useStoreModal((state) => state.isOpen);

 useEffect(() => {
  if (!isOpen) {
   onOpen();
  }
 }, [isOpen, onOpen]);

I'm not sure exactly what useStoreModal does, but you can't add a state value that changes to the dependency array of the same useEffect that calls a function that changes that state. It creates a black hole of re-renders.

I don’t fully understand what you mean. Could you be clearer, please ?

I added the useStoreModal to the code to better understand the problem. The useStoreModal component is supposed to open a modal component when we reach the /home and no store is created. The user cannot close the modal until he creates a store.

This is a fairly common issue in react when using the use effect to update state. Basically if you update state in the use effect and that state is also included in the dependencies, the state will update triggering the use effect to run again. This causes an endless loop. Or as written in the error message - Maximum update depth exceeded.
